# how to trigger .catch on status 400 from server

Tags: angular, client, try-catch, bad-request

catch is not getting triggered when i get status code 400 from my server... maybe someone can help me out.

this is my code

```
fetch('/api/orders/addOrder', {
          method: 'POST',
          mode: 'cors', 
          cache: 'no-cache',
          credentials:'include',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          redirect: 'follow', 
          referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', 
          body: JSON.stringify(objToSend)
        })
        .catch(() => {
          alert('all the orders on this date are taken. please choose another date')
        });
```

theres no need to publish my server side code cuz i know for sure i am getting status code 400 for this request on some cases but the catch is not getting triggered any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

from the fetch api documentation

```
fetch('your api url', {})
.catch((err)=> {

})
```

the catch method will catch every http error that comes from the server
so you can make your code to something like this

```
  fetch('/api/orders/addOrder', {
          method: 'POST',
          mode: 'cors', 
          cache: 'no-cache',
          credentials:'include',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          redirect: 'follow', 
          referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', 
          body: JSON.stringify(objToSend)
        }).catch((err) => {
                 console.log(err);
                }
         );
```

and this should work

solution two
you can make your own handler by using the es6 chain methods
and try something like this

```
function handleErrors(response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw Error(response.statusText);
  }
 return response;
 }
fetch('/api/orders/addOrder', {
          method: 'POST',
          mode: 'cors', 
          cache: 'no-cache',
          credentials:'include',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          redirect: 'follow', 
          referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', 
          body: JSON.stringify(objToSend)
        })
.then(handleErrors)
.then(response => console.log("ok") )
.catch(error => console.log(error) );
```